# Why won't the ng-change will be executed in this Angular JS test?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to test out **`Angular JS`**    the way everytime I modify the a text input, its corresponding model object will be printed to console.

I got this markup:

It's wrapped by a div with `ng-controller="datosPersonalesController"` attribute. And an outer div with `ng-app`.

This is the JavaScript:

```
function datosPersonalesController ($scope) {

    $scope.name = "Paco"

    $scope.datosPersonales = {

        nombre:     "",
        apellidos:  0,
        edad:       0,
        telefono:   "",
        celular:    "",
        mail:       "",
        fb:         "",
        direccion:  ""
    }

    $scope.testAngular = function  () {

        console.log($scope.name)
    }
}
```

I include the JS file inside `<head>`.

However, tested at a browser it won't print anything to console. I actually would like the model to be `$scope.datosPersonales.nombre` but changed to name to check.

I include this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9eUKN/) where it should be displayed within a `<p>` but doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your fiddle, the script that defines the controller is running when the page is loaded. Angular runs before that and it can't find the controller. Change the dropdown on the side to put the script in the body.

This should now work...

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="datosPersonalesController">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputNombre" placeholder="Nombre(s)" ng-model="datosPersonales.nombre" ng-change="testAngular()">
        <p>{{datosPersonales.nombre}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6H3Dg/)

Comment: Should the library and the aditional JS files be included at body, then?

Comment: Load Angular first, then the JS file that defines your controller. What other JS files do you have?

Comment: So far, only the controller one. I include the angular lib at head and the controller file at the begin of body but can't make it work at my site.

Comment: What errors are you getting in your JavaScript console? Is the JS file loading properly?

Comment: No error is shown at console and simply nothing is printed, I tried logging text but didn't work